# Capistrano deployment stop suddenly at 'puma:restart' stage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, puma

I'm trying to deploy a ruby on rails app on AWS instance using Capistrano. I followed these three tutorial mostly [How to deploy your rails app to Amazon EC2 using Capistrano, nginx and puma](https://shreyamundra90.medium.com/how-to-deploy-your-rails-app-to-amazon-ec2-using-capistrano-nginx-and-puma-6cef3ddf867), [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.matthewhoelter.com/2020/11/10/deploying-ruby-on-rails-for-ubuntu-2004.html) and [How to Deploy Ruby on Rails App to AWS EC2 with Capistrano?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmdvC2RsjVI&ab_channel=CloudGuru).

The server runs as expected if I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails-7-app/current/config/puma.rb` command manually at aws instance. Afterward, the site becomes live at IP:3000. But when Capistrano tries to start or restart server it suddenly stops.

Here is what Capistrano logs after running `cap production deploy` from local machine.

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 0.998s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-4af81a0fde8f532060e3.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-4af81a0fde8f532060e3.sh
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 0.901s
00:04 git:check
      01 git ls-remote https://github.com/warhammer327/rails-7-app.git HEAD
      01 2da3378c22c59b87cf9e867fbb0787191a28ebcc
      01
      01 HEAD
      01
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.430s
00:05 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/shared /var/www/rails-7-app/releases
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 0.956s
00:06 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/log /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/cache /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/soc…
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.407s
00:08 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/config
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.011s
00:15 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /var/www/rails-7-app/repo
00:16 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/warhammer327/rails-7-app.git
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.245s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
      02
      02 remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
      02
remote: Counting objects:  28% (2/7)
      02 remote: Counting objects:  42% (3/7)
remote: Counting objects:  85% (6/7)
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
      02
      02 remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 4 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
      02 Unpacking objects:  25% (1/4)
      02 Unpacking objects:  50% (2/4)
      02 Unpacking objects:  75% (3/4)
      02 Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4)
      02 Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 368 bytes | 184.00 KiB/s, done.
      02 From https://github.com/warhammer327/rails-7-app
      02
      02    cddfcc6..2da3378  main       -> main
      02
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.345s
00:20 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.012s
      02 git archive main | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
00:25 deploy:set_current_revision
      01 echo "2da3378c22c59b87cf9e867fbb0787191a28ebcc" > REVISION
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.298s
00:26 deploy:symlink:linked_files
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/config
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.273s
      02 rm /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/config/database.yml
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.679s
      03 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/config/database.yml
    ✔ 03 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
      04 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/config/master.key /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/config/master.key
    ✔ 04 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.007s
00:35 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133 /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/tmp /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/ven…
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.006s
      02 rm -rf /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/log
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.682s
      03 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/log /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/log
    ✔ 03 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
      04 rm -rf /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/tmp/pids
    ✔ 04 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 0.992s
      05 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/tmp/pids
    ✔ 05 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.007s
      06 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/cache /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/tmp/cache
    ✔ 06 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
      07 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/sockets /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/tmp/sockets
    ✔ 07 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.014s
      08 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/vendor/bundle /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/vendor/bundle
    ✔ 08 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.007s
      09 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/public/system /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/public/system
    ✔ 09 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.349s
      10 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/public/assets /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/public/assets
    ✔ 10 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.011s
01:03 bundler:config
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local deployment true
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.276s
      02 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local path /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/bundle
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.163s
      03 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local without development:test
    ✔ 03 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.590s
01:10 bundler:install
      The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied, skipping installation
01:11 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile

      01 
      01 yarn install v1.22.19

      01 
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 
      01 ⠁
      01 


      01 
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...

      01 
      01 
      01 [---------------------------------------------] 0/45

      01 
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 
      01 [#############################################] 45/45

      01 

[-----------------------] 0/23

      01 

[-----------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/347
      01 
      01 [#########################--------------------------------------------] 128/347
      01 
      01 [###################################################------------------] 256/347

      01 

      01 
      01 [----------------------------------------------] 0/46

[4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 
      01 ⠁ 
      01 
      01 [##############################################] 46/46
      01 
      01 [1/1] ⠂ esbuild
[1/1] ⠄ esbuild

      01 


Done in 0.66s.

      01 
      01 yarn run v1.22.19
      01

      01 
      01 $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
      01
      01
      01   app/assets/builds/application.js      229.6kb
      01
      01   app/assets/builds/application.js.map  399.7kb
      01
      01

      01 
      01 Done in 0.17s.
      01

      01 
      01 yarn install v1.22.19

      01 
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01
      01 
      01 ⠁
      01 

      01 

      01 
      01 success Already up-to-date.
      01

      01 
      01 Done in 0.14s.
      01

      01 
      01 yarn run v1.22.19

      01 
      01 $ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules
      01

      01 
      01 Done in 0.66s.
      01
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 5.437s
01:17 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/assets_manifest_backup
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.271s
      02 cp /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-d871e12b4d304eab6a512ddf5f9bd98e.json /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/2…
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.454s
01:23 deploy:migrate
      [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
01:25 deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 3.249s
01:28 deploy:symlink:release
      01 ln -s /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230503041133 /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/current
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.008s
      02 mv /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/current /var/www/rails-7-app
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
01:31 deploy:cleanup
      Keeping 2 of 3 deployed releases on ###.###.###.###
      01 rm -rf /var/www/rails-7-app/releases/20230502115027
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.007s
01:35 deploy:log_revision
      01 echo "Branch main (at 2da3378c22c59b87cf9e867fbb0787191a28ebcc) deployed as release 20230503041133 by n****a" >> /var/www/rails-7-app/revisions.log
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.006s
01:36 puma:restart
      01 sudo /bin/systemctl restart puma_rails-7-app_production
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.008s
```

The deployment process just stops in `puma:restart` stage. Applying `cap production puma:start` also yields similar result. The log in this case says,

```
00:00 puma:make_dirs
      01 mkdir /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/sockets -p
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 0.900s
      02 mkdir /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids -p
    ✔ 02 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.448s
00:02 puma:start
      01 sudo /bin/systemctl start puma_rails-7-app_production
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@###.###.###.### 1.002s
```

My capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/rails"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/puma"
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma 
#install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Daemon
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd
#require "capistrano/passenger"



# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.2.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "6.2.2"

# Bundle and transpile JavaScript [https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails]
gem "jsbundling-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails", "~>1.0"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Bundle and process CSS [https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
gem "cssbundling-rails"

#Bundle simple form
gem "simple_form", "~> 5.1.0"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Devise gem
gem "devise", "~> 4.8.1"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
gem "sassc-rails"
gem 'sshkit'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'





# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"
  
  gem 'capistrano'         
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'   
  gem 'capistrano-rails'   
  gem 'capistrano-bundler' 
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'   
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor', git: 'https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor.git'
  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

config/deploy.rb:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
#lock "~> 3.16.0"
#server '###.###.###.###', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :application, "rails-7-app"
set :repo_url, "https://github.com/warhammer327/rails-7-app.git"

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/rails-7-app'

set :user, fetch(:user)

set :use_sudo, true
set :branch, 'main'

set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key config/database.yml}
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :keep_releases, 2
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/master.key}

set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 16]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :pty, true
set :rbenv_ruby, "3.2.1"

set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end
  before :start, :make_dirs
end


namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do

      # Update this to your branch name: master, main, etc. Here it's main
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/main`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/main"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        invoke 'puma:restart'
      end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  # after  :finishing,    :restart
end


# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", 'config/master.key'

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "tmp/webpacker", "public/system", "vendor", "storage"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

config/puma.rb:

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `worker_timeout` threshold that Puma will use to wait before
# terminating a worker in development environments.
#
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

#application_path = 'home/ubuntu/rails-7-app/shared/tmp'

#bind "unix://#{application_path}/sockets/puma.socket"

#bind "unix:///home/ubuntu/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/sockets/rails-7-app-puma.sock"

# Allow puma to be restarted by `bin/rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

config/deploy/production.rb:

```
server '###.###.###.###', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{web app db}
set :ssh_options, {
forward_agent: true,
auth_methods: %w[publickey],
keys: %w[/home/n******a/server-keys/test-*****.pem]
}
```

On aws instance /etc/systemd/system/puma_appname.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma Rails Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/rails-7-app/
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails-7-app/current/config/puma.rb'
#ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec puma -C /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/config/puma.rb
#ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec pumactl -S /var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state stop
TimeoutSec=15
Restart=always

#added from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042621/puma-systemd-script-doesnt-start-puma
PIDFile=/var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On aws instance /etc/systemd/system/puma.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/rails-7-app
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/puma -lc 'bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rails-7-app/config/puma.rb'
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/puma -C /var/www/rails-7-app/config/puma.rb
PIDFile=/var/www/rails-7-app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried following up several stackoverflow posts and a few other blogs and mostly edited puma.service & puma_appname.service.

In case of successful deployment capistrano log says something similar to this after `cap deploy puma:start`.

```
 using conf file /home/deploy/myapp/shared/puma.rb
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.4.0 do bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/myapp/shared/puma.rb --daemon
      01 Puma starting in single mode...
      01
      01 * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Private Caller
      01
      01 * Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
      01
      01 * Environment: production
      01
      01 * Daemonizing...
      01
```

Comment: From the amount of information you provided it's absolutely impossible to tell what the problem is. Sorry, but I don't think anyone has a whole day to read through all of this. Ideally you should pick a single tutorial and use that. Following three different ones probably generates three times as many problems.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel As I described on the top, the for some reason capistrano is unable to start or restart puma on the aws instance. It does not show any error, seems it just gets disconnected or something similar happens. 

As this is the first time I'm deploying, my assumption is that there is something wrong with configuration. For this reason I provided all the config related information.

Comment: What version of Capistrano were you running?